# Searching for a unique value across multiple parenthesis with RegEx on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Example

```
var value = "foo bar (foo(bar)(foo(bar)))";
```

And the value you want is

```
(foo(bar)(foo(bar)))
```

And not

```
(foo(bar)
```

Comment: Hard to do in JS as it doesn't have recursive regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As elclarns notes, JS doesn't have recursive regex, but regex is not the only tool, parenthesis counter should work, well

```
  var x = "foo bar (foo(bar)(foo(bar))) foo bar";
  var result = "";
  var cnt = 0;
  var record = false;
  for(var i=0; i<x.length; ++i) {
    var ch = x.charAt(i);
    if(ch=="(") { ++cnt; record = true; }
    if(ch==")") --cnt;
    if(record) result+= ch;
    if(record && !cnt) break;
  }
  if(cnt>0) record = ""; // parenthesis not enclosed

  console.log(result); // (foo(bar)(foo(bar)))
```

This of course captures only the first parenthesis, but you can record them all in array and choose the longest result. This should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
var re = /\(.*\)/
var result = re.exec(value) //["(foo(bar)"]
```

It then will catch the biggest string between parenthesis.

Comment: This is usually defined as "lazy" or "greedy" pattern.

Comment: I believe you have that backwards and `?` will return the result mentioned in the question whereas it will return the full thing without the `?`.  http://jsfiddle.net/gm55q/